# XCart Checkout Steps

Tags: x-cart

I am using xcart. In the checkout process, I want to skip the step that appears after a customer clicks the add to cart button on the product page. It should take them to a page that shows the product and the text "Added to your shopping cart".

I want to take them directly to the "view cart" page, right before the checkout page.

Anybody have any ideas about how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> i want to take them directly to the "view cart" page, right before the checkout page.

Just enable "Redirect customer to cart after adding a product" option in X-Cart admin back-end -> Settings -> General settings

Comment: Well, probably there is a bug in your X-Cart. Contact our techs at https://secure.qtmsoft.com